# is permission needed when choosing image from gallery on android?

Tags: java, android, mobile

i'm currently making an apps that can upload choosen image from gallery to mysql database via php, but now i'm in confuse because i read on android 11 or above you need a storage access permission.
So, is permission to access the storage is needed when you only need to choose image from gallery?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you do not need any permission using ACTION_PICK, ACTION_GET_CONTENT or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: Can you point to where this is documented?