# Image permission dialog not showing

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-permissions

I'm trying to request a permission from the user to access the device images so the users can pick and image and upload it to firebase. the issue is nothing is showing. I tried to add some logs but cant seem to understand why. I want to be able to use the default android dialogs. check the code. Note my app support version from android 8 Oreo to Android 14.  Thank you

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_IMAGES = 1;
 btnBrowse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            checkAndRequestReadImagesPermission();
            Image_Request_Code);

        }
    });
    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            UploadImage();

        }
    });
}
private void checkAndRequestReadImagesPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
           
            Log.d("Debug", "Permission rationale should be shown.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_IMAGES);
        } else {
            // Permission has not been granted yet, and rationale does not need to be shown.
            Log.d("Debug", "Requesting permission without showing rationale.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_IMAGES);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("Debug", "Permission is already granted. Proceeding with image selection.");
        // Permission is already granted, proceed with image selection.
        selectImage();
    }
}

private void selectImage() {
    imagePickerLauncher.launch("image/*");
}
```

Comment: `trying to request a permission from the user to access the device images so the users can pick and image and upload it to firebase. ` You do not need any permission to do so. Further you did not tell which permission.

Comment: Wasn't there a requirement by google to do so? to ask the user about anything related to internal storage. this is the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES". it included in the code section as well

Comment: @blackapps I tagged you just incase you haven't been notified

Comment: You need to request a permission to access arbitrary files. You don't need a permission to let the user select a file your app gets access to.

Comment: You were asked to mention that permission at the fist lines of your post. Not afterwards.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by arbitrary files. @dan1st

Comment: Yes, I edited the question. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You just dont need any permission for what you want to do. Thats all.

Comment: If you want to access a file on the storage that is not part of your app storage in any way _and_ you don't use a file picker (i.e. the app decides which file to access), you need a permission to access the file. Otherwise (in your case), you don't need it (because you are using a file picker).

Comment: I see. Thank you. if it its possible to write an answer so I can mark it as solved so the other developers can benefit from it.

Comment: I see, when we use file picker we already define the type, meaning it will only access that part and that what the app needs. @dan1st

Comment: actually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72586826/is-permission-needed-when-choosing-image-from-gallery-on-android is a better one

Comment: yes, will that still be valid for the new changes google released yesterday for the developers? " For a more privacy preserving experience for users, we’re introducing the Photo and Video Permissions policy to reduce the number of apps permitted to request broad photo/video permissions (READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_MEDIA_VIDEO). Apps may only access photos and videos for purposes directly related to app functionality. Apps that have a one-time or infrequent need to access these files are requested to use a system picker, such as the Android photo picker.   "@dan1st

Comment: Those new permissions also have nothing to do with picking fies with any of the many file pickers there are. Sadly you did not even tell which one you use. Although we could guess which one.

Comment: I see, I used to let users pick images without permission but when I read the policy changes I implemented the solution in the question thinking that I have to do it. from what I understand not its not needed

Comment: `the new changes google released yesterday` Please post a link.

Comment: it was an email for the new policies for android developers. That's why I didn't provide an email.

Comment: just found it. 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/14016515?sjid=12091823039127482684-EU @blackapps

Comment: check it out please. I forgot to tag you @blackapps

Comment: check it out please. I forgot to tag you @dan1st

Comment: I already read that an hour ago. There is nothing to say exept that it is pretty clear told there that if using an image picker you dont have to bother.

Comment: Okayy, thank you so much. I'm double checking with you and @dan1st to make sure everything is correct which is. I'm still a new developer things like that do confuse me sometimes.

Comment: I think that new policy is saying that apps (on Google Play) shouldn't request access to the entire storage for accessing some images.

Comment: Sorry the late reply. My app is on the play store